# InvalidPipeArgument for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pipe

I began studying about Async Pipe and i am stuck at this....

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })
export class AppComponent {
   courses$;

   constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
       this.courses$ = db.list('/courses');
     }
   }
```

Here is my component.ts

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let course of courses$ | async">
    {{ course }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

and here is my component.html

I am getting the error `InvalidPipeArgument for pipe 'AsyncPipe'`
I am a beginner in Angular so please help..

Comment: try using `courses$ : Observable<any>;`

Comment: this.courses$ = db.list('/courses').valueChanges();

Comment: this solved the issue

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to:

`this.courses$ = db.list('/courses').valueChanges();`

This will solve your issue.